# Can't update bind value on blur or on setValue

Tags: angular

I have a number which is bound to localValue. I would, when I hit maximum value on set(localValue) or on blur, update value for upper max value  (in sample is 50).

But it seem  it work only once after set or blur didn't work anymore (blur never work).

[PlunkerSample](https://plnkr.co/edit/hBC3jtJ9VirQW3gf5lXQ?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Test On blur update with valid value (Value max is 50)</h2>
      <h2>If you type 9999 --> 5099</h2>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="localValue" (blur)="OnLostFocus()"/>
    </div>
  `
})
```

...

```
  private localValue: number;

  public set localValue(value: number) {
    if(value > 50){
      value = 50;
    }

    this._localValue = value;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would define your variable this way:

```
private _localValue: number;
```

I'm not sure that using the `blur` event is necessary in your case since the value is managed by setters and getters.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rDsX72pSGxFAnBuDPHfq?p=preview.

**Edit**

I would create rather a custom value accessor for your input. Here is a sample:

```
const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MaxValueAccessor), multi: true});

@Directive ({
  selector: 'input[max]',
  host: { '(input)': 'doOnChange($event.target)' },
  providers: [ CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class MaxValueAccessor extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      super.writeValue(value);
    }
  }

  doOnChange(elt) {
    var val = elt.value;
    if (val>50) {
      val = 50;
    }
    elt.value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
  }
}
```

You could use this directive this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Test On blur update with valid value (Value max is 50)</h2>
      <h2>If you type 9999 --> 5099</h2>
      <input max type="number"  [(ngModel)]="localValue"/>
      <h2>Messaged: {{messaged}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ MaxValueAccessor ]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  private localValue: number;
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rDsX72pSGxFAnBuDPHfq?p=preview.

Comment: Your solution didn't work ! If I type "9999" I got "5099" I expect got "50"

Comment: I updated my answer and provided a new plunkr. Feel free to tell if it suits your needs...

Comment: Yeah your solution work !  But any idea why my set validation is trigger and work first time but not subsequent ?

Comment: You're welcome! I think that your `_localValue` property contains the right value but the input value is desynchronized. It seems that Angular2 doesn't detect the change and update the input value... Perhaps it's because of the getter.