# Angular 2 time input two way binding

Tags: angular

I have a problem with 2 way binding a time input. I can not find a way to accomplish this.

Here is an example in plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gyn8ER1LDBkkI0HieLZE?p=preview

And here is my code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      Date: <input [(ngModel)] = "date"/>
      Time: <input type="time" [(valueAsDate)] = "date" />

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  date = new Date();
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several way to do that:

- Set the `type` to `date` in your input but it's not cross browser:

  ```
  <input type="date" .../>
  ```
- Use an Angular2-compliant date picker like ng2-datepicker.

  ```
  <datepicker [(ngModel)]="test.date"></datepicker>
  ```

  See this question for more details:

  - [How to use date picker in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788543/how-to-use-date-picker-in-angular-2)
- Another way would be to implement a custom value accessor to parse / format the string of the input from / to a date object. Here is a way to do that:

  ```
  const DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValueAccessor), multi: true});

  @Directive({
    selector: 'input[type=date]',
    host: { '(input)': 'doOnChange($event.target)' },
    providers: [ DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
  })
  export class DateValueAccessor extends DefaultValueAccessor {
    onChange = (_) => {};
    onTouched = () => {};

    writeValue(value:any):void {
      if (value!=null) {
        super.writeValue(value.toString());
      }
    }

    doOnChange(elt) {
      var val = elt.value;
      this.onChange(new Date(val));
    }
  }
  ```

  See this question for more details:

  - [Angular 2. Prevent input and model changing using directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770846/angular-2-prevent-input-and-model-changing-using-directive/36770988#36770988)

Comment: I ended up using the ngbootstrap time not date, but still this is not what I am looking for. I need to resolve the time input issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a flexible visual time picker for angular 2+, you can install it easily using:

```
npm install amazing-time-picker --save
```

then, open your `app.module.ts` and add to your module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AmazingTimePickerModule } from 'amazing-time-picker'; // this line you need
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AmazingTimePickerModule // this line you need
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please read api to understand how to use this module here:

https://github.com/owsolutions/amazing-time-picker

It would looks something like this:

[image: Angular time picker, Angular 2 time picker, Clock picker]